# Parsing Array of Objects without main index key

Tags: android, json

My JSON Array is like:
[{"id":"1","name":"ABC"},{"id":"2","name":"XYZ"}]

And I want it to be parsed.

I did this:

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args)
{
    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    //Log.e("JSON Data", json.toString());
    return json;
}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)
{
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // Getting JSON Array from URL
    mydataset = json.getJSONArray("data");
    Log.d("Till Here", mydataset.toString());
}
```

But the "Till Here" is not coming in log, it means I am doing something else.
Can someone help?

Comment: Please note this is a sample from my code, to avoid unnecessary confusions and to be to-the-point.

Comment: Why do you use a "try" ?

Comment: You are adding an try catch block. Did you get anything in catch block

Comment: do you get 'json' correctly? Does Log.e("JSON Data, json.toString())); returns something?

Comment: Yes, json has the data, I debugged it already

Comment: @Maxouille I copied it from my code, I have Catch part in my code, but forgotten to remove try part here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url){
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONArray jArray = null;

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();

            jArray = new JSONArray(result);            
        return jArray;
    }

}    

 protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        //Log.e("JSON Data", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = jsobj.getString("id");

                        String name = jsobj.getString("name");
                        Log.e("MainActivity"," >>> id = " + id + " >> name = "  +name);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                }
    }
```

Comment: This line is giving error JSONArray properties = new JSONArray(json); My result is in json variable. It says message Cannot resolve constructor

Comment: Change jParser.getJSONFromUrl  return type to JSONArray.

Comment: It gives error cannot resolve method. I think there is some issue in JSON Parser. Can you please refer any good JSON parser if it is so. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer. http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON is a good JSON parser

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `optJSONArray()` mehod like

```
mydataset = json.optJSONArray("data");
```

since its doesnt need to be surrounded by try/catch but you should be carefull about null.
Also we don't see what is `JSONObject json` - is it `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` already? If its the 2nd then your code is wrong since you need to operate `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`:

```
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args)
{
    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    Log.d("JSON Data", json.toString());
    return json;
}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json)
{
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // Got JSON Array from URL already
    Log.d("b4 tHere", String.valueOf(json));
    mydataset = json;
    Log.d("Till Here", String.valueOf(mydataset));
}
```